# get_error_or_404 returning a tuple with no attributes

Tags: python, django

Learning django and recently can't get this error to be fixed. Error says:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'title'.
```

My views.py file looks like this:

```
def post_detail(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=3),
    context = {"instance": instance,
               "title": instance.title       # Line of error
              }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)
```

template file post_detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
{{ title }} logged in.<br><br></h1>
{{instance.title}}<br>
{{instance.content}}<br>
{{instance.updated}}<br>
{{instance.timestamp}}<br>
{{instance.id}}<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content =  models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Can someone point me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the `get_object_or_404`, so you wrap the result in a *singleton* tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=3),
#                                       ^ comma
```

Note the comma (`,`) at the end of the line. This means that you *wrap* the result of the `get_object_or_404(..)` call into a *singleton* tuple (a tuple with *exactly* one element). So if the result would have been `42` (of course here that is not possible), by writing a comma at the end, you construct a tuple `(42,)`.

If you **remove the comma**, then `instance` will have the result of the function call itself.

Comment: I'm so sorry for posting this. This is embarrassingly novice of me.Thank you so much.